# Using Node.js RESTful routes, how can I change the color of something after it is edited?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, html-table, crud

I'm sort of new to RESTful routing and CRUD, so I'm not sure how to go about this or what the best way to do this is. I have an HTML table populated with data from a MongoDB collection called environments. The table is populated by looping through the collection with a `forEach`. When an entry is edited (1 entry = 1 row of the table), I use a form to use a PUT method and update the data that way.

I'd like to be able to indicate when something has been updated by changing the background color to yellow after it's updated (sort of like highlighting). I was thinking I could add a checkbox or something next to each form input that a user could check when they edit something, and then the background color of the table cell would change depending on whether or not that checkbox was checked....but I have no clue how to do that with routes like this :(

I've included what I think is necessary but if you'd like to see more code pls let me know:

app.js routes:

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    methodOverride = require("method-override");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/epims", {
 useNewUrlParser: true,
 useUnifiedTopology: true
});

app.use(methodOverride("_method"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));

//EDIT ENVIRONMENT ROUTE
  app.get("/environments/:id/edit", function(req, res){
      Environment.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundEnvironment){
          if(err){
              res.redirect("/");
          } else {
              res.render("edit", {environment: foundEnvironment});
          }
      });
  });

//UPDATE ENVIRONMENT ROUTE
app.put("/environments/:id", function(req, res){
  Environment.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.environment, function(err, updatedEnvironment){
    if (err) {
      res.redirect("/environments");
    } else {
      res.redirect("/environments/" + req.params.id);
    }
  });
});
```

html table:

```
  <table class="environment">
    <tr>
      <th colspan=2>ePIMS</th>
      <th colspan=2>Region</th>
      <th colspan=2>HCHC</th>
      <th colspan=2>Membership</th>
    </tr>
    <% environments.forEach(function(environment){ %>
      <tr>
        <td class="td"><%= environment.ePIMS %></td>
        <td class="td"><%= environment.region %></td>
        <td class="td"><%= environment.HCHC %></td>
        <td class="td"><%= environment.membership %></td>
    <% }); %> 
      </tr>
  </table>
```

edit form:

```
    <form action="/environments/<%= environment._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="environment[ePIMS]" placeholder="ePIMS" value="<%= environment.ePIMS %>" />
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="environment[region]" placeholder="Region" value="<%= environment.region %>" />
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="environment[HCHC]" placeholder="HCHC Instance" value="<%= environment.HCHC %>" />
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="environment[membership]" placeholder="Membership"  value="<%= environment.membership %>" />
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Is the color change going to persist or not?

Comment: @AvivLo yes I'd like it to persist and only change back when the user chooses to

Comment: What templating engine are you using?  Is there an option to color the HTML table at the front end? If yes, we can just send the color names from the back end which will be used by the templating engine to replace, let's say, a CSS attribute called color at the front end which will then be applied.

Comment: @AvivLo im using ejs. I was thinking of doing something like that but I've never done that kind of thing so I wasn't sure where to start

Comment: I will post the potential solution in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this on the back end:

> Back End:

```js
//I am using arrow function here to make the code looks cleaner
app.get('/environments/:id/edit', (req, res) => {

    //I am using promise here to make the code looks cleaner
    Environment.findById(req.params.id)

        .then(result => {

            res.render("edit", {
                environment: foundEnvironment,

                //Maybe the color can be here
                colorHere: 'yellow'
            });

            //The error will be caught here if any. No need of if(err) anymore
         })
        .catch(err => res.redirect("/"));

});
```

> Front End:

```html
//I use handlebars most of the time. I am not 
//sure about the ejs syntax. But it should be
//something like this

<h1 style="color:<%=colorHere%>;">This is a Blue Heading</h1>
```

Comment: hmm okay i see where you're going with it. I don't think this exact method is possible for passing data but i kind of have a better idea of which direction I can take. thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome. Btw, perhaps using `var` and start using `let` and `const` now.